# Printing ESC Codes In LX 350

Tags: windows, printing, lpt

We have a Old Software that Prints through LPT port and we are passing ESC code 14 & 18 to double-width printing and this works perfect when we use LPT port but when change the same printer to USB port all fonts print same small size and it prints character 14 as --> ♫.
We have tried Generic Text Printer drivers via USB, but it wont print ESC codes it prints as .(dot) for 14 but not large double-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Windows API Escape() function

http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/torry/showcode.php?id=716